# How can I change class of an image from NoneType to NumPy Array in OpenCv?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying Face recognition for the very first time in Google Colab

I'm not able to get the type of image as a NumPy Array though I have loaded the required modules.

here's my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To plot images and show information on image

import numpy as np

from skimage.feature import hog  # To perform HOG calculations 
from skimage import data, exposure

import cv2  # To read images and perform certain operations on the image

# from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\sachin-tendulkar.jpg", 1)
print(type(img))
```

I'm getting the output as follow :

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

What can be done? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on a Google Colab you can't have access to your local computer memory, thus `"C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\sachin-tendulkar.jpg"` will not be accessible for OpenCV, resulting in a `None` object.

Have you tried uploading your image to Colab's local memory? This should work perfect.

Comment: Oh. Okay. How do I upload the image to Colab's local memory? Since, I'm all new to use Colab, I don't have much idea about this.

Comment: You can either mount your drive to Colab or just upload manually your files. In both cases, just go in the left panel and select the 'folder' tab. To upload manually, just drag your file into this panel, to mount drive just click on the third icon on top of this panel.